# Linux shell command : su authentication failed

Tags: linux, authentication

I upgraded current OS to latest version. i am unable to do su from admin to root user.

I checked /etc/password, /etc/shadow, unix_chkpwd and su permission, everything looks ok
i dig into the /etc/pam.d/ configuration made some changes to see if any luck, but none of them worked.

Below is the error log i can see in system logs, it would be great if any one help on this issue

Note: I am able to telnet to root.

```
unix_chkpwd[7868]:, check pass; user unknown
unix_chkpwd[7868]:, password check failed for user (root)
su[7279]:, pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=2000 euid=2000 tty=/dev/pts/3 ruser=admin rhost=  user=root
unix_chkpwd[7874]:, check pass; user unknown
unix_chkpwd[7876]:, check pass; user unknown
unix_chkpwd[7876]:, password check failed for user (root)
su[7279]:, pam_authenticate: Authentication failure
su[7279]:, PAM 1 more authentication failure; logname= uid=2000 euid=2000 tty=/dev/pts/3 ruser=admin rhost=  user=root
su[7279]:, FAILED su for root by admin
su[7279]:, su session not logged to /var/log/sulog
su[7279]:, - /dev/pts/3 admin:root
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

in a new machine root might not have a password
try `sudo su`

or `sudo passwd root`
for more info you can see this page
https://askubuntu.com/questions/347818/what-is-the-default-root-password-when-was-never-set-at-installation-time

Comment: Thanks for the comment, sudo binary does not present in latest linux package, moreover i am able to telnet using root and password, which means root password already exists.