# su root failed on Mac

Tags: macos, shell

I tried to use the command "su root" on Mac OS Monterey version 12.3.1, but response was always Sorry, is there any possible reasons other than the wrong password?

I checked the link [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70699857/linux-shell-command-su-authentication-failed ] as this man did before. According to the specification, it says that [root and users in group wheel can run anything on any machine as any user], the belonging of me myself is wheel absolutely. See attached image. However, I did not succeed after trials.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWNvm.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhLHl.png)

Thank you so much !
Best Regards,
Juan K.N

Answer (score 0):

When you do `su root`, you need to input `root` password.

To become `root`, we usually do `sudo su -`, then input your own password.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS the root user is DISABLED by default. Also note, macOS is not Linux! You should really use sudo as @Philippe suggested.

If you want to enable the root user there are two methods:

1. In a Terminal window:

   trev@macmini8 [/Users/trev] $ sudo su -
   Password:
   macmini8:~ root# passwd
   Changing password for root.
   New password:
   Retype new password:
2. Choose Apple Menu (top left) > System Preferences
   Choose Users and Groups
   Click Login Options
   Click Join
   Click Open Directory Utility
   From the menu bar in Directory Utility
   ...    Choose Edit > Enable Root User
   ...    Enter the password that you want to use for root

Comment: Is the root you mention here is Admin ?

Comment: The instructions are for "root" - they are not for "Admin".